# Format TextView to Display a Song

Tags: java, android, textview, format

I want my `TextView` to look like this:

Jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh

Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh

Jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh

Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh

Here is the code from `activity_main.xml` for the `TextView`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOut"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/song"
/>
```

as you can see, the last attribute `android:text="@string/song"` sets the text to be a string from `R.strings` In `R.strings` my song looks the way I want it to, but when I run the app, it all looks like this

Jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh
Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh
Jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh
Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells
Jingle all the way
Oh, what fun it is to ride
In a one horse open sleigh

How can I make it look the way I want it to?

Comment: Add newlines to your string resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the end line character \n in the strings.xml file if you want carriage return to happen. Your song would begin like this:

```
<string name="song">jingle bells, jingle bells\njingle all the way\n...</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string in `strings.xml` should look like this:

```
<string name="song">
    Jingle bells, jingle bells\n
    Jingle all the way\n
    Oh, what fun it is to ride\n
    In a one horse open sleigh\n\n

    Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells\n
    Jingle all the way\n
    Oh, what fun it is to ride\n
    In a one horse open sleigh\n\n

    Jingle bells, jingle bells\n
    Jingle all the way\n
    Oh, what fun it is to ride\n
    In a one horse open sleigh\n\n

    Hey, jingle bells, jingle bells\n
    Jingle all the way\n
    Oh, what fun it is to ride\n
    In a one horse open sleigh\n\n
</string>
```